# ejb3 jboss7 arguments

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1, argument-passing

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 and I have to pass an argument between two session beans.
Is it possible to pass arguments by reference from a local stateful session bean to a local stateless one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it works between local client and local client view. It is not only possible, but it is the way how it's specified to work. I do not try to rephrase in details, because this is quite nicely written in EJB 3.1 specification:

> Session beans may have local clients. A local client is a client that
>   is collocated in the same JVM with the session bean that provides the
>   local client view and which may be tightly coupled to the bean. A
>   local client of a session bean may be another enterprise bean or a web
>   component.
>   ...
>   The arguments and results of the methods of the local client view are
>   passed “by reference”[1]. Enterprise beans that provide a local client
>   view should therefore be coded to assume that the state of any Java
>   object that is passed as an argument or result is potentially shared
>   by caller and callee.
>
> [1] More literally, references are passed by value in the JVM: an
>     argument variable of primitive type holds a value of that primitive
>     type; an argument variable of a reference type hold a reference to the
>     object.